# Looking for documentation of package2-descriptor.json to create a package2 version with sfdx

Tags: salesforcedx

I try to create a package2 salesforce package.

> sfdx force:package2:version:create -i XXXXX -d force-app/
>   ERROR running force:package2:version:create:  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'force-app/package2-manifest.json'.

I understand that I must create a manifest file before creating a version :

> sfdx force:package2:manifest:create -d force-app/
>   ERROR running force:package2:manifest:create:  The package2-descriptor.json must exist in the specified directory.

However, I can't find any documentation about this file format.

I understand that it's a beta/pilot version but don't know where to look for pilot projects documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I found some examples in a merge request : https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-dreamhouse/pull/146/files